# ERR Slot xxx is already busy (Redis::CommandError)

Tags: redis, key-value, key-value-store, redis-cluster

I want setup redis cluster with 6 nodes (node1, node2, node3, node4, node5, node6), which has 3 masters and 3 slaves. Each node has this configuration file

redis.conf

```
port 6379
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes.conf
cluster-node-timeout 10000
appendonly yes
```

I get error when create the cluster. Create command:

```
redis-trib.rb create --replicas 1 node1:6379 node2:6379 node3:6379 node4:6379 node5:6379 node6:6379
```

Error:

```
>>> Creating cluster
Connecting to node node1:6379: OK
Connecting to node node2:6379: OK
Connecting to node node3:6379: OK
Connecting to node node4:6379: OK
Connecting to node node5:6379: OK
Connecting to node node6:6379: OK
>>> Performing hash slots allocation on 6 nodes...
Using 3 masters:
node6:6379
node5:6379
node4:6379
Adding replica node3:6379 to node6:6379
Adding replica node2:6379 to node5:6379
Adding replica node1:6379 to node4:6379
S: 1f13819038ba983bb8355f54cb8cec19d2b29e01 node1:6379
   replicates 534745088c8b403b81d7e48a22d2e317fb420a38
S: 711461862393664b46d73db6561631f40de29561 node2:6379
   replicates f503fe6fd52c73e446267795111ae6ea95495829
S: 204fa4e23b08e2c6ad80b0aca271fc380bc6885d node3:6379
   replicates fe6a8e88afdb2796c09fcc873b37ba90c2ba6d79
M: 534745088c8b403b81d7e48a22d2e317fb420a38 node4:6379
   slots:10923-16383 (5461 slots) master
M: f503fe6fd52c73e446267795111ae6ea95495829 node5:6379
   slots:5461-10922 (5462 slots) master
M: fe6a8e88afdb2796c09fcc873b37ba90c2ba6d79 node6:6379
   slots:0-5460,6918 (5462 slots) master
Can I set the above configuration? (type 'yes' to accept): yes
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/redis-3.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:114:in `call': ERR Slot 16011 is already busy (Redis::CommandError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/redis-3.2.2/lib/redis.rb:2646:in `method_missing'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/redis-3.2.2/lib/redis.rb:57:in `synchronize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/redis-3.2.2/lib/redis.rb:57:in `synchronize'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/redis-3.2.2/lib/redis.rb:2645:in `method_missing'
    from /home/hadoop/projects/ramin/redis-3.0.5/src/redis-trib.rb:205:in `flush_node_config'
    from /home/hadoop/projects/ramin/redis-3.0.5/src/redis-trib.rb:667:in `flush_nodes_config'
    from /home/hadoop/projects/ramin/redis-3.0.5/src/redis-trib.rb:666:in `each'
    from /home/hadoop/projects/ramin/redis-3.0.5/src/redis-trib.rb:666:in `flush_nodes_config'
    from /home/hadoop/projects/ramin/redis-3.0.5/src/redis-trib.rb:1007:in `create_cluster_cmd'
    from /home/hadoop/projects/ramin/redis-3.0.5/src/redis-trib.rb:1388:in `send'
    from /home/hadoop/projects/ramin/redis-3.0.5/src/redis-trib.rb:1388
```

I also did these, but also got same error message

1. use ip address instead of hostname
2. remove nodes.conf in each nodes

Comment: Have you tried issuing a [FLUSHALL](http://redis.io/commands/flushall) and then [CLUSTER RESET SOFT](http://redis.io/commands/cluster-reset)?

Comment: @thepirat000 thanks, works correctly and i also changed hostname to ip address

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How said @thepirat000 (in all nodes did FLUSHALL and then CLUSTER RESET SOFT) i also changed hostname to ip address